# typeof x gives one result only when using in for ... of loop ie the last value result

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new Map();
a.set(1,2);
a.set(3,4);
a.set('man','good');
a.set('4','hi');
for (var [x,y] of a){
    console.log(x+' '+y);
}
```

when i wirte the above code i get the output as follow:-

```
1 2
3 4
man good
4 hi
```

But when I replace console.log with typeof x , it just shows the typeof last x i.e., 4. why does it skips the rest three???

```
var a = new Map();
a.set(1,2);
a.set(3,4);
a.set('man','good');
a.set('4','hi');
for (var [x,y] of a){
    typeof x;
}
```

output:-

```
'string'
```

Comment: Works for me, whats the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/9dfj4h5o/

Comment: I assume you know `typeof x;` doesn't log or output anything, if you are testing this code in browser debugger, it just shows the result of last operation. use `console.log(typeof x);`

Comment: why can't I just use typeof x instead of console.log(typeof x) ?

Comment: _"why can't I just use typeof x instead of console.log(typeof x) ?"_ What is expected result?

Comment: same as console.log(typeof x)

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` does not log anything. You should use `console.log()`. I honestly don't really know whats going on, but you would never have any reason to care about this. You can't depend on this for logging. I did try this to try and understand how the implicit logging works and it seems like it only logs the last value of the for loop.

```
> x = [1,2,3,4]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> for (let i of x) i
4
```